# sweet alert CSS styles not being applied in Vue app

Tags: css, vue.js, sweetalert2

I have installed vue-sweetalert2 in my Vue app (version 2.6). I included the following in the `main.js`:

```
import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';

Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);
```

I have a simple button with a click handler:

```
 <button v-on:click="alertDisplay">Click me</button>

     alertDisplay() {
      this.$swal('Heading', 'this is a Heading', 'OK');
     },
```

This works as expected. When the button is clicked the sweetAlert modal shows but it appears in the very bottom left of the page without any styling. I have looked around but I can't find a clear reason or solution to this issue in the context of a Vue app.

Any ideas are very appreciated!

Comment: import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';

Comment: Thanks. I just found that solution right before reading your comment.

Answer (score 3):

When you are using vue-sweetalert2, you have to import the css file to get the result that you want.

In your main.js file use the following code line:

```js
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.css';
```

Additionally if you want to change the font-family use the following css code:

```
.swal2-title {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
}
```

I hope it helps you ;)